# Flatten object with collection properties

Tags: c#, json

Suppose that I have a following object instantiated.

```
public class Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonExtensionData]
        public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> AdditionalProperties { get; set; }
    }

Parent parent = new() { Id = 1, Name = "Parent", AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Property", "SomeProperty" } } };
```

This would be translated to the following JSON structure:

```
 parent {
           id: 1,
           name: "parent",
           additionalProperties: {
             property: "someProperty
           }
         }
```

Instead I would like to flatten it and return the following json object to the user.

```
 parent {
           id: 1,
           name: "parent",
           property: "someProperty"
        }
```

I could handle additional properties with dynamic or extendo objects but I don't want this, I need it as strongly typed as possible, so I decided to store dynamic properties inside the dictionary.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Why do you want to change the way it gets flattened? What's the goal?

Comment: First json I have posted is default behavior and how it's currently converted to json, the second json is the format I want to achieve.
So, **property: "someProperty"** needs to be on the same level as other parent.json properties and not nested inside **additionalProperties {}**.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but why in the world would you want to do that? is what I am asking.

Comment: @JuanR: The additional properties approach comes into play, when you deserialize a json string into a class and you need to save all properties which didn't match your class properties. Normally these values are discarded, but by using this dictionary, you can save them and also serialize them back, when you serialize your class.

Comment: @Olvier
That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't tell us, which JSON serializer you are using, so I tested Microsoft and Newtonsoft. Both will throw an error if your property is of type `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>`, but if you change it to be `Dictionary<string, object>` it [works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D8zin8):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Parent parent = new() { Id = 1, Name = "Parent", AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Property", "SomeProperty" } } };

        var newtonSoftJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);
        Console.WriteLine(newtonSoftJson);

        var microsoftJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(parent);
        Console.WriteLine(microsoftJson);
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionData]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties { get; set; }
}
```

> {"Id":1,"Name":"Parent","Property":"SomeProperty"}
> {"Id":1,"Name":"Parent","Property":"SomeProperty"}

Answer (score 1):

since you are using JsonExtensionData, the dictionary should be < string, object >

```
Parent parent = new() { Id = 1, Name = "Parent", AdditionalProperties = 
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Property", "SomeProperty" } } };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

result

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Parent",
  "Property": "SomeProperty"
}
```

test

```
parent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json); //ok
```

class

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Serge, I was faster. 

Comment: @Oliver It was about the same, since SO makes 2 min delay

Comment: Oh this is great.

Answer (score 0):

The JSFlatten library can help you: [Library link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonFlatten/)

Before
[image]

After
[image]
Source: [Tutorial](https://techtutorialsx.com/2020/10/25/csharp-flattening-a-json/)

Comment: This could be helpful, I will have to figure out an elegant way to remove that "prop1" prefix though.